# In R, create a text file if script doesn't complete successfully

Tags: r, error-handling

Is there a way to create a text file if an R script has an error? I am in a situation where an external process is initiating the R script and will send me an email once the file is created, so if the R script doesn't complete then I get no email...which would be fine but I am wanting a way to be notified that there was an error. So, in the event that R has an error I would like to create a text file, or similar, that is a simple error.txt so that my external process will see that in the folder there is an error.txt file and will send me an email notification. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Try `help(tryCatch)`.

Comment: Couldn't you just create an error.txt file manually in your R-Code and in the last line of your R-Code it will be deleted again? So when the job is successfully finished there won't be any error.txt?

Comment: I was thinking about creating a file in the beginning and then deleting at the end, but was wondering if there was a better/more elegant solution.